# How to switch window in NodeJS WebDriver?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, popupwindow

How do I get a window handle of a new window that opens up in WebDriverJS when there is no `getWindowHandles()` function?

I need to `switchTo` a new window to login with Facebook for a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called `getAllWindowHandles()`in NodeJS Webdriver see here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html